# SQL Server Successful login audit

Tags: sql-server, session, sql-server-2008-r2, audit

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 and have an active `Successful_Login_Group` audit on it. The output audit file saves about 20000 rows in 10 minute.

I just want to audit user login start time and session duration.

I have usually 40 active session each time.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am assuming you created a server level auditing via *Server Audit Specifications*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding it correctly, you just need the succesful and failed login information, but instead you are stuck with a giant audit file.

1. Have you tried just turning on the native SQL Server 2008 R2 Security Connection logging? Simplest way that could do the trick as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6769173/2295317
2. If that doesn't work for you and you are looking to code up your own logging in SQL take a look at this msdn post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/08/16/703079.aspx. It's a bit old, from 2006 but it applies to SQL Server 2008 R2 and there is a walkthrough of how to set that up.

Hope this helps.