# Track all logins on to a single SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

Thanks in advance for any help.

We have a particular database on a SQL Server 2012 box along with about 20 other databases.

What I require is a method/script/audit (open minded about the solution) that will simply track anyone who logs in (successfully / unsuccessful) to this one particular database on the server (the single database is the key as the end user does not want information on any of the other databases that sit on the server), it also has to log time the attempt was made and it must track the logins via SQL Server or the application itself that is attached to the database.

Once we have this information we need to simply store that somehow. I say somehow as the storing part depends on the solutions recommended to me, so I’m open minded about this too.

Any help would be great as I'm scratching my head on this one.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769099/where-are-sql-server-connection-attempts-logged

Comment: Its not, maybe i'm not explaining it correctly. I don't want to log every login to every database on the server I just need to log all logins to a single database on the server

Comment: @Matt, You log on to the sqlserver, not a special database. Maybe you rather want to know who has used (read/write) a database. The sql server profiler can log that for you.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a tool built into SQL Management Studio for this.

Please see the attached link for [Configure Login Auditing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175850(v=sql.110).aspx)

Once it has been setup, all events will be recorded in the error log.

Comment: But does this not just track all logins to all databases? I need to just track the logins of one database and then we need to send the end result file to the customer either via email or a secure location on our network.