# How to check the access log in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, access-log

I have a remote windows server and SQL Server 2008 installed. How can I check the access log of SQL Server with the IP address that tried to access the DB?

I tried in `SQL Server Management Studio -> Management->SQL Server Log`. It doesn't show the IP address.

Comment: You may take a look at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46009/get-username-and-or-ip-address-responsible-for-a-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, if you missed to set up login auditing, you can't.
By default, only failed logins are logged. You have to set your server instance to log both failed and successful logins.

You can find some details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769099/where-are-sql-server-connection-attempts-logged)