# Retrospective Tracking of Manual Table Editing in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is there anyway to retrospectively determine if a table (or rows/fields) have been manually edited in SQL Server 2016.

Yup, you read that right. I'm trying to unravel some inconsistent data on a production database. Based on my interactions with the user and analysis of the table in question (sequential IDs don't make sense, LastUpdateDate fields inconsistent, etc.), I suspect that the table was manually edited.

Yup, it's the production database.

I appreciate that I won't be able to get what fields have changed but if I can show that the user HAS manually edited the table/database, we can work to resolve the situation.

Comment: The database server does not track how did what nor what application was involved. So I think the short answer is no. You might be able to derive some very rough information based on analyzing the transaction log files - but that depends greatly on the presence of those files, an advanced knowledge of their usage, and a (not free) tool to investigate them. Seems there are much more significant security / permissions issues here

Comment: And fyi identity values can have some significant jumps in values due to engine caching - so that is not necessarily an indication of anything unusual. And oddities in datetime recording can indicate something fiddling with the OS date and time values.

Comment: Are the connections/logons to your production database logged? If so, you could [start there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769099/where-are-sql-server-connection-attempts-logged).