# Login error when accessing database from Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server database from Powershell and for some reason I keep getting this error:

```
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user 'revadmin'."
At line:1 char:5
+     $conn.Open()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

I know that my credentials are valid, because if I copy/paste them into SSMS, I can connect without a problem.

This is the code that I'm using to connect:

```
$connString = "MyConnectionString"
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connString
$conn.Open()
```

EDIT: This question was closed as a duplicate, but the suggested questions don't address the issue of a login failure error, which was the topic of the question. The answer was that the problem was caused by a character in the password of the connection string that PowerShell interpreted as the beginning of a variable. This issue was not immediately obvious and could be easily overlooked. My reason for posting this question and answer was to document this solution for others who face a similar problem with the same cause so they can quickly identify and resolve it.

Comment: Did you check [the error log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769099/where-are-sql-server-connection-attempts-logged) for a failure reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the password in my connection string includes a `$`, which Powershell interprets as a variable. The solution is to use a backtick before the $, like so: `` Pa`$sword ``

Comment: The crazy thing about this is that the one thing I would never include in an online question is the password in my connection string, so I don't know how I would have solved this if one of my co-workers with access to the credentials didn't realize this and point it out.

Comment: Single quotes, `'`, around the string would also work, as variables aren't evaluated in these. See [quoting rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.3) for details.