# ASP.NET remote SQL Server authentication error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

Apologies, lots of threads on this topic but I can't find one to resolve my issue.

Existing environment: Windows Server 2008 R2 single node with IIS, ASP.NET web app and local SQL Server 2014 database.

New environment: Windows Server 2022 with SQL Server Web license and SQL Server 2022. Separate web / IIS Windows 2022 server.

I stood up the environment, can access the web app from the browser, but when I go sign-in and authenticate I get an error

> Login failed for ''

Existing `web.config` connection string:

```
 <add name="ConnectionString" 
      connectionString="data source=localhost;initial catalog=AP;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
```

I updated the remote database to use SQL Server authentication and setup a `user1` account as db owner. I can access the remote database from the web server as `user1` via SSMS, but assume I need to update something on my IIS?

```
<add name="ConnectionString" 
     connectionString="data source=10.1.0.5,1433;initial catalog=AP;Integrated Security=False;User ID=user1;Password=pass1" />
```

Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated;

Thanks
Boyd

Here is the error from the SQL Management side:
Message

```
Login failed for user ''. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Integrated authentication only. [CLIENT: 10.1.0.4]

Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 58.
```

EDIT: Still working on some of the other requested details, but here is the error from the asp web app:

```
    [SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user ''.]
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager) +1481
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1150
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +70
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +1124
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +103
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1598
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +159
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +382
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +307
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +198
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +422
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +199
       System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +193
       System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +521
       System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable) +153
       Data.DAL.UserProfileDSTableAdapters.UserProfileTableAdapter.GetUserByUserName(String UserName) in C:\Users\boydj\source\repos\DAL\UserProfileDS.Designer.cs:2801
       
Data.UserBLL.GetUserByUserName(String userName) in C:\Users\boydj\source\repos\BLL\UserBLL.cs:231
       Classroom.SignIn.IsActiveUser(String userName, LoginFailureReason& loginFailureReason) in C:\Users\boydj\source\repos\Classroom\Authentication\SignIn.aspx.cs:517
       Classroom.SignIn.ValidateUser(String userName, String password) in C:\Users\boydj\source\repos\Classroom\Authentication\SignIn.aspx.cs:398
       Classroom.SignIn.signInButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\boydj\source\repos\Classroom\Authentication\SignIn.aspx.cs:347
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +138
       System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +150
       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5445
```

**EDIT**
I found resolution.  I had the typo in my connect string.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Where's the rest of the error message? The full error messages often contain information, such as in stack traces, that give you a general idea as to what the problem may be.

Comment: Can you access the new server using SSMS? If you can see the Error Logs node then check for Error 18456 events, take note of the `State` numbers that they mention and compare them against the `State` numbers listed at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to determine the cause of the login failure.

Comment: Thanks I’ll post the full stack dump, also  when you say error logs node, where are you referencing?

Comment: When connected using SSMS it will be ServerAndInstanceName > Management > SQL Server Logs. These are filterable views over the [ERRORLOG files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/viewing-the-sql-server-error-log) that SQL Server records in the file system.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that IIS is using Windows Authentication, and for whatever reason the new server doesn't recognize the user. Are the servers connected to the same AD domain? Are they even in an Active Directory domain? Is IIS using an App Pool user? Are you using IIS Impersonation?

Comment: By default, IIS sets the impersonate attribute to false. Since the environment is new, the IIS configuration should also be kept the same as before. At present, detailed error messages is required to determine the cause.

Comment: Working to get the details and a fresh error based on some of the changes i've made

appreciate the help

Question, is it required for them to be in an AD domain together...trying to configure with the least amount of effort, but keep them secure

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, i added the error message

Whats bizarre to me is that i can sign in via SSMS SQL Authentication on the web server to the DB node.  I also queried the DB to ensure that the server property is SQL and Windows autehntication.  And I've rebooted the nodes multiple times

Comment: Seems like your target SQL Server instance is configured to use only "Windows Authentication mode," i.e.: Active Directory/Kerberos/Windows Logons as opposed to SQL Logons where usernames+passwords are registered directly on the instance. Via SSMS if you right-click on the server/instance node and go to Properties > Security, is it set for "Windows Authentication mode" or "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode"?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning its definitely set to sql authentication and windows, i set the property and restarted. also queried server props and confirmed.  Agree it's weird the server is giving that error.  I used the sql user i created  via SSMS "SQL Authentication" on the remote note and was successful, it's just when going through the app.

Also user1 is set as the dbowner to reduce likelyhood of other permission issues

Comment: To address your other question in the comments: yes, the web server and the SQL Server should be on the same authentication domain - or at least on domains that trust each other.

Comment: The error message doesn't lie (note the sooner you post the actual error the quicker these things can be uncovered) are you certain you're connecting to the correct server?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, apologies Nick what is your question.  I only have 2  servers, a web server and a db server.  

I can connect with SQL authentication from the web server via SSMS to the DB server.  I think that is demonstrating that SQL Authentication is infact working, but agree the error message produced is black and white.

I'm pointing my local IIS on my dev laptop to the DB and going to try to debug through visual studio....

but if you have any other suggestions please let me know

thanks again

Comment: I suggest you check the SQL Server logs. Reproduce a successful manual login and identify that in the logs. Then reproduce the failed login and identify that in the logs. (you might need to enable this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6769173/1690193)

Answer (score 0):

first you must configure the Microsoft SQL Server database for remote access
To configure the Microsoft SQL Server database for remote access:

1.Launch SQL Server Management Studio.

2.In Object Explorer, right-click on your server and select Properties.

3.Click Connections.

4.Under Remote server connections, select Allow remote connections to this server.

5.Click OK to save the changes. Changing this setting does not require restarting the server.

6.Ensure TCP/IP protocols are enabled and your firewall is set to allow port 1433. For information on enabling TCP/IP, see https://help.ivanti.com/wl/help/en_us/ava/6.1/avalanche/install/setupSQLServer.htm.

then set trustconnection to false and set TrustServerCertificate to true in connection string, like this:
"Server=user_server_address;DataBase=database_name;Trusted_Connection=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;user id=your_userid;password=your_password";